# Generating a RSA key-pair with GnuTLS in C

Tags: c, gnutls

How do I generate a RSA key-pair in GnuTLS in C? What function do I need to call? Do I need to initialize the library first?

Answer (score 1):

You should check [Public key algorithms](https://www.gnutls.org/manual/html_node/Public-key-algorithms.html) as per documentation. Basically initialize private key, then generate private key. Then you can export the generated keys.

Comment: Is there a list of options for gnutls_pk_algorithm_t? I can't find it on the web. I would like to use it for RSA.

Comment: Everything should be in documentation: https://gnutls.org/reference/gnutls-gnutls.html#gnutls-pk-algorithm-t